# how to change the gender and name of the voice in pyttsx

Tags: python

i am using pyttsx for python 2.7.  I find that the original voice of pyttsx does not sound good.i am trying to change the gender and name of this voice. is there a way to do this? and how would i do this? any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you refer to the library's documentation for this. This is not a programming specific question, but a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows then the pyttsx is using the default language that is being used for the Microsoft Speech application.
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\MS-Anna-1033-20-DSK`, check the registry, if you have only one language over there then you don not have much of a choice, you can try to install some new sounds and then they the default example from the [homepage](https://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/v1.1/engine.html) of pyttsx.

Comment: Well when i have it show me want voice they are using it shows me that registry, When i looked on their documentation there is a section that says something about the voice metadata and then under that is class.pyttsx.voice.VOICE then under this is say age, gender, id, languages, name. will that change the gender(the class.pyttsx.voice.voice) here is their documentation: https://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0/engine.html

Comment: well, anyone has a tip on linux? the docs are not that conclusive,